# Upscaling video with different filter on each side

Tags: video, ffmpeg, scaling

I need scale up video from one DOS game using [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/). But with [Nearest-neighbor interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) on left side and [xBR](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xbr) filter on the other one.

**Input (320x200)**

[image]

**Output (1280x800)**

[image]

Here is a command, where's xBR processing whole screen...

```
ffmpeg
    -i input.avi
    -sws_flags neighbor
    -vcodec libx264 -strict -2
    -preset veryslow -qp 0
    -filter:v "xbr=4"
    output.mp4
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Left & right

[image: Different filter on each side]
<sub>I cropped the image to make the output size smaller just for display purposes.</sub>

This will show the whole video on each side. Left is [`xbr`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xbr) and right is [`scale`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale).

### Using [`hstack`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack)

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -filter_complex \
"[0:v]xbr=4[bg]; \
 [0:v]scale=iw*4:-1:flags=neighbor[fg]; \
 [bg][fg]hstack,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

All input streams to [`hstack`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) must have the same pixel format and same width.

### Using [`pad`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) & [`overlay`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay)

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -filter_complex \
"[0:v]xbr=4,pad=iw*2[bg]; \
 [0:v]scale=iw*4:-1:flags=neighbor[fg]; \
 [bg][fg]overlay=w,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

This method is slower and more complex than just using [`hstack`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack).

---

## Left & right: With 10 pixel border

[image: With 10 pixel border]

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -filter_complex \
"[0:v]xbr=4,pad=iw*2+10[bg]; \
 [0:v]scale=iw*4:-1:flags=neighbor[fg]; \
 [bg][fg]overlay=w+10,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

---

## Split screen: left & right

[image: Split screen: left & right]

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -filter_complex \
"[0:v]xbr=4[bg]; \
 [0:v]scale=iw*4:-1:flags=neighbor,crop=iw/2:ih:ow:0[fg]; \
 [bg][fg]hstack[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

---

## Top & bottom

[image: Top & bottom]

### Using [`vstack`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack)

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -filter_complex \
"[0:v]xbr=4[bg]; \
 [0:v]scale=iw*4:-1:flags=neighbor[fg]; \
 [bg][fg]vstack,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

All input streams to [`vstack`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack) must have the same pixel format and same width.

### Using [`pad`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) & [`overlay`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay)

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -filter_complex \
"[0:v]xbr=4,pad=iw*2[bg]; \
 [0:v]scale=iw*4:-1:flags=neighbor[fg]; \
 [bg][fg]overlay=0:h,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

This method is slower and more complex than just using [`vstack`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack).

---

## Split screen: top & bottom

[image: Split screen: top & bottom]

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -filter_complex \
"[0:v]xbr=4[bg]; \
 [0:v]scale=iw*4:-1:flags=neighbor,crop=iw:ih/2:0:oh[fg]; \
 [bg][fg]vstack[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: Big thanks! You saved me many hours ;-). [Result](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48zAgbsr_Es)