# FFmpeg putting one video above its filtered version

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to make a combination of two videos.
The first video is my input unaltered while the second one (placed below the first) is a filtered version of the first video.
I'm able to filter the first video as I want but I've got difficulties in making an output of the two versions combined as I'd like to.

Even following this other question does not help me:

[Upscaling video with different filter on each side](https://superuser.com/questions/918837/upscaling-video-with-different-filter-on-each-side)

Here is the command that I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i ./media/video/video_with_alpha.mov \
-c:v libx264 -b:v 400k -tune zerolatency -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -movflags +faststart -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 64k \
-filter_complex \
    "[0:v] fifo, lutrgb=r=maxval:g=maxval:b=maxval [T1]; \
     [0:v] format=rgba, fifo, lutrgb=r=minval:g=minval:b=minval [T2]; \
     [T2][T1] overlay [out_alpha]; \
     [0:v][out_alpha] overlay=0:360[out]" \
-map '[out]' -map 0:a ./media/output/video_rgb_above_alfa.mp4
```

The result I get is the two videos overlapped one to the other like this:
[image]

While what I want is like this:
[image]

Does any of you know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `-b:v 400k -tune zerolatency`, and why use `fifo`?

Comment: The [linked question has an updated answer](http://superuser.com/questions/918837/upscaling-video-with-different-filter-on-each-side), so your question can be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers but I found my solution with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i ./media/video/video_walpha.mov \
-filter_complex "[0:v] fifo, lutrgb=r=maxval:g=maxval:b=maxval [1]; \
[0:v] format=rgba, fifo, lutrgb=r=minval:g=minval:b=minval [2]; \
[2][1] overlay [alpha]; \
[0:v]pad=iw:ih*2[stage]; \
[stage][alpha] overlay=0:h [merge]; \
[merge] scale=1280:-1 [out]" \
-map '[out]' -map 0:a \
-c:v libx264 -b:v 400k -tune zerolatency -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -movflags +faststart -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 64k \
./media/output/video_mobile_rgb_alfa.mp4
```

What I was missing was in fact the "pad" filter.